# アニメーション処理を書いてないにもかかわらず、キーボードに合わせてアニメーションするのは何故ですか？

Tags: swift, ios

ストーリーボードに素朴にUITextViewを置いています。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var hogeTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.hogeTextView.delegate = self

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let keyboardSize = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect else { return }

        self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y - keyboardSize.height
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 else { return }

        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        if (text == "\n") {
            hogeTextView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

上記コードについてです。

`self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y - keyboardSize.height`

の部分と

`self.view.frame.origin.y = 0`

についてアニメーション処理を入れていないにもかかわらず、キーボードがせり上がってくる速度と同じ速度で、`UITextView`がアニメーション付きでせり上がります（厳密にはせり上がっているのは `self.view`）。何故でしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

いまSwiftをいじれる環境がないのでサッと解説します。

UIView の背後には CALayer があります。

```swift
// UIView
var layer: CALayer { get }
```

この CALayer のインスタンスは描画に関する情報をもっていて、UIView はそれを元に画面にビューを描画します。CALayer はこの描画を担当するオブジェクトをデリゲートとして参照します。

```swift
// CALayer
weak var delegate: CALayerDelegate? { get set }
```

UIView の特定のプロパティの値の変更は CALayer のそれの変更にあたります。CALayer は特定の値の変更に際し「暗黙のアニメーション」を実行します。

アニメーションもオブジェクトで、このアニメーションオブジェクトは CALayer のデリゲート、つまりここでは UIView が用意します。UIView は CALayerDelegate プロトコルに適合し、実装するメソッドでそれを返します。

```swift
// CALayerDelegate
optional func action(for layer: CALayer, forKey event: String) -> CAAction?
```

あなたが気にしているアニメーションはここで返されるアニメーションオブジェクトによって実行されています。
標準では始点と終点のみを指定して 0.25 秒かけて描画されるアニメーションだったと思います。

---

#### 参考

[action(forKey:) - CALayerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayerdelegate/2097264-action)

より詳しく基礎から学ぶ場合は [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) をお読みください。

Comment: `@IBAction func tapButton(_ sender: Any) { self.view.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.origin.y - 300 }` とボタンに処理を書いてみたところ、この場合はアニメーションしません。デフォルトのアニメーションが作動するのはどのようなときなのでしょうか？